# Can i mix non bounded parameters in prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-injection

Like i'm doing with `$_SESSION['userid']` here:

```
function changeEmail($newEmail){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("update `users` set `email`=? where `userid`={$_SESSION['userid']} limit 1");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$newEmail);
    return $stmt->execute();
}
```

Since: The value of the `$_SESSION['userid']` is generated from database (via auto_increment integer) so no risk of SQL injection. Also, i'm assuming that concatenating the value is little bit faster than binding.

Comment: You can, but it is STILL NOT SAFE. Why not safe I hear you ask? Because you probably didnt make sure that whatever you put into the SESSION was 100% safe, and even if you did, as its the session, code that someone else wrote may be placing stuff in there, so you have to trust that they did it carefully as well. **It's just not worth the risk**

Comment: filtration and validation data before any query!

Comment: Your two assumptions are just wrong. But yes - You can mix them for wrong reasons too.

Comment: Shared hosting can share the same session scope. A malicous user on the same shared php server can realy screw you over with that one :)

Comment: Additionally to the above, another side-benefit of using parameters is that it reduces the risk of unexpected syntax errors which could occur when you concatenate strings - e.g. if you were adding a "surname" string, and the user's surname was `O'Grady` - it's not dangerous per se, but it would cause a SQL syntax error if the string wasn't properly escaped. One thing that parameterisation does is handle the escaping for you correctly. So even if you decide you aren't concerned about other threats, you should parameterise anyway for that reason. There's no benefit at all to _not_ parameterise

Comment: @ADyson - Bound parameters are not "escaped" and don't need to be, because they are not parsed.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel well perhaps I don't entirely understand the internals. But let's say for example my query is `SELECT * from x WHERE Surname = ?` and then I bind `O'Grady` as the surname...then something somewhere must create a SQL string with the correct quotation marks round the value, and ensuring the quote in the value is not a problem? Or is it done a different way? Perhaps I'm naively assuming it constructs a literal SQL string. I am genuinely interested. (But I think the point still stands that if you use parameters it will remove the possibility of the quote mark causing a syntax error.)

Comment: @ADyson - The bound parameters are send to the DB separately from the prepared query. So no - they will not be "integrated" into the query. (Except when you use ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES in PDO - which is not recommended.) Anyway - Using bound parameters, you don't need to think about escaping special characters.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Ok thanks. So the db engine itself is the one which would combine the parameters and the prepared query in order to execute it. That's useful to know. Excuse my naivety on that point. But it sounds like we agree that using parameters removes the need to worry about escaping.

Comment: @riggsfolly I think your comment should be the answer.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript Can the malicious user edit my `$_SESSION['userid']` to make SQL injection possible?

Comment: @gom yes, they have full control over what gos in the session

Comment: I agree with others who say there's no downside to using parameters for all the variables you want to bind to this query. It also simplifies your coding standards. When you get a new team members it's easier to tell them, "always use parameters," instead of "sometimes use parameters, except for some cases of content we think is safe." Then you need to explain which types of content is safe, and why, and prove it, etc. That's an unnecessary time-sink.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but you really shouldn't!

3 points:

1. You need to bind all parameters no matter where they originated from, otherwise your code is still vulnerable to SQL injection.
2. Binding parameters makes for a cleaner code. You don't need to worry about correct quoting, interpolation or data types.
3. There's no benefit to concatenation/interpolation. The code will not be faster or clearer or better in any way. You bind one parameter already, so why not bind the rest?

As long as you put the variable input directly in SQL your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use data binding always!